# How to receive a soap message with attachment in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, soap

I have a webservice in c# and I'm receiving soap messages with attachments.
This is the wireshark log of one request

```
POST /scripts/vivo_sdp/ReceiveMmsNotificationService.asmx HTTP/1.1 SOAPAction: ""Content-Type: multipart/related; type="text/xml"; start="<sgp@email.com>"; boundary="----=_Part_1012.1378126647" Host: 1.1.1.1:0000 Connection: closeContent-Length: 5078 ------=_Part_1012.1378126647Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitContent-ID: <sgp@email.com>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <ns1:NotifySOAPHeader xmlns:ns1="http://www.huawei.com.cn/schema/common/v2_1">
            <ns1:spRevId>XXXXXXX</ns1:spRevId>
            <ns1:spRevpassword>XXXXXXXX</ns1:spRevpassword>
            <ns1:spId>000370</ns1:spId>
            <ns1:serviceId>0100218100</ns1:serviceId>
        </ns1:NotifySOAPHeader>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns2:notifyMessageReception xmlns:ns2="http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/multimedia_messaging/notification/v2_4/local">
            <ns2:correlator>01090212572613003106</ns2:correlator>
            <ns2:message>
                <messageIdentifier>hwiuFVMFHjTfK9</messageIdentifier>
                <messageServiceActivationNumber>XXXXXXX</messageServiceActivationNumber>
                <senderAddress>tel:XXXXXXXXXX</senderAddress>
                <priority>Default</priority>
                <dateTime>2013-09-02T09:50:58-03:00</dateTime>
            </ns2:message>
        </ns2:notifyMessageReception>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
------=_Part_1012.1378126647Content-ID: <oQpSk>Content-Location: 01smilContent-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitContent-Type: application/smil; name=01smil<smil><head><layout><root-layout width="240" height="320" /><region id="Image" width="100%" height="70%" left="0%" top="0%" fit="meet" /></layout></head><body><par dur="8000ms"><img src="Bunny.svgz" region="Image" /></par></body></smil>
------=_Part_1012.1378126647Content-ID: <Bunny.svgz>Content-Location: Bunny.svgzContent-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitContent-Type: application/oct-stream; name=Bunny.svgz...........Z.n.G.}v...,...3....!m QR` ....b....ea.J.(....9=$EzI..\..k..8....S.N.....?_7.&......@..4.....jzy8........~..._...j2....7.......I.....n^/5..5.6...Us...f6o.....^M.S/../............_|..i...q.....~{....l.....W.f.
..p......:....O.>h.o.........yp.fv9.jv~..j|7..!...!&.1.......k..Asuq88}.........p..j..T.!/.__M..m..R.........A.K...O^4.W.....................
...7.H..`B...G.....t........O......>..a./.n......lr7...T+\....
.....
n_..C.;W..A........b.IV..76.N.:....;.....]..\<.z1....BkM..m..u.sP2.{Lj.(..[.d.+.56I+..O...x1!.1F..V./...\..>..S.
.p..l06......Rqm0.eLe..G........7..Xp
,......|...+c.D.k..z.}j.`*ii.W....7.V.&%.8Z;...0J..`.[.t..q..S0%...}..........p..W.{..F..
.......p{:......yz7..c'.?.s..:`&...........z.=...."..B.......3./....~.[.C.b......x...8I.>..i..3....{r>..\\M..J!..W'?.O..rq.....\r....1......HA......A
..)......z8p../9...&..'....
?;......|8..|>.z.9.UBn./E..G....F.|j.
\
.|A..1..7.Ms.....$.....r
...n|s
...(.Q.......<....
......\.[.Kg.....%)[..............(y.c..........XN.7.'...]....[$...h..M.}H.....?[.........q....y.#.....uE..[....k.I..A..Pu.."..z'C<A.OS.."*]c.u.V.Rj7....k..}<.z..jR.y..sJO.D..$.e#$.h......34l.}'..G.Y..B.p.hD...W...<....#../
z......."e...N....v.s...~..3V&...^..h.p...m.O<.O....MI...'........... ......0..
NH.=.1.3...e.qL....T.<......Ya...r.o.0.o.&S..b)..`.P.J..24..x0z..6..-...N."....Qc..0...G....5.3.G.....6.C........f$e.G.\..e..4.7.J}F".q.8..^.P...&).:.]|u.".7..W.....spE).$.....$..0s^M..t..y....4"..{..-.v..H..I...{M....L.v......d.M..<.b.m`H.I.N..Y.5pfk..q#....6#..Y:.:.V.L.7...s....(...t.%..:.k.o\...@.E..............,.....?)........h....:.9>.HA.g..-}....o.|.2.H#L...(...\r"....=..C....Y......J.c...:`..Jf.+[0...H.U..q.
.].l.@X..k0..#.;.sU......1...#d.."m..4\...L.. .....5..=@.....i....)x.....W.yu........V.v....{.S?Fn{.c'..N%.I.v`Cl.......&:j]U...^ ..n*......V..)%w@..n.{4S.Q.8.*R.D.}.b.H@.@Y
.
....N...PxK........T}V..L.0...MQ`%H=.6H..j.HU..T.{.....b/......B........-=A(w). yE...O%?...t.......,.Y.!.......-..K....fG....
`...6.,.823..4.I.*..@...C.V2=.]\erW...W...!.
J..cT....@.m.2R......."J.f............}.M.qO,#...n.eFpq~..BA.W:...h.OA......>Ih.?..=.#...%Y.9`>..v.$j...3.......!8=>:>y>..
Z...7.b..@..".V..f\.C..7........D..*`y..vM..7f.......Pn.
..T.u..Cd...3.sp.>.g.=5...:..`b-..!h.....fr......K.....1.Fh+
}eLB(...X(+@N`..P....+P._o,..z4........Y.21+....e.g.{.Y.^l..Z..3,>.G...v...lf2.}....?...!vs..Y@....
T...x....
.......g[....X..'v.R...A.l.Q
.f.}x..l.T...`.....-.O.Q.............R..-.1K*..j..R.j...T[E..M..j.....L...P.%'670e.r.........Q..h3oe.,.......-.N......}..kg.....M#.....q)i.1...]&v.`..e.....]..#...1B..&(1..3..B.....j..T;.%..,....D...........L{..r?...5r"[D0Y=.._r.........Q..J.
...C...X{..l.z..c;......1G.Z.....\...u../y...?.....'.G._.U.N...y....)8.....%-.........).%...!....SE.vz.0;....=....I.Y.....Fv.=..HUL.....<B...v..... Y....+...i...p|L...Pa9...)@#..O...3K..q..S....p... hE..or.k...Vb.^8.".Td...N..g..U}...du........6>kSW...i..(.L.S.`.0..?1.7....e..tH`..>b.y..>...
....4..t...~W.t|....9.wNN...._......giE.....@.I. 0j..#v.....*^.&%.%L...+.........e....l...J"y
Q.2..]c.
.&..*$O....L.]A...;....k1..k+...E..._P....fc..R..v).oq.1....@I..i>.......P...Y`^....3....82..R_fY).'j..B.a?......M.......$R`......
.8...bF..*.y..`~..k@....*cc..M..i.......Z."W
.`!..L&.R"z...
`......).8.k...K&......0)P....R..."..B....d.W.,....:.....S...u...d<o...S..S.q3X.pz3.o<~.g..=....q.....".v%..
------=_Part_1012.1378126647--
```

and this is the answer that my server is giving

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server ErrorConnection: closeDate: Mon, 02 Sep 2013 12:57:27 GMTServer: Microsoft-IIS/6.0P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"X-Powered-By: ASP.NETX-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727Cache-Control: privateContent-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8Content-Length: 754
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <soap:Fault>
            <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
            <faultstring>The root element for the request could not be determined. When RoutingStyle is set to RequestElement, SoapExtensions configured via an attribute on the method cannot modify the request stream before it is read. The extension must be configured via the SoapExtensionTypes element in web.config, or the request must arrive at the server as clear text. ---&gt; Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.</faultstring>
            <detail />
        </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

This is the signature of the method

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[SoapDocumentService(RoutingStyle = SoapServiceRoutingStyle.RequestElement)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
public class ReceiveMmsNotificationService : WebService, IMessageNotificationBinding, IReceiveMessageBinding
{
    [WebMethod]
    public notifyMessageReceptionResponse notifyMessageReception(notifyMessageReception notifyMessageReception1)
    {
        notifyMessageReceptionResponse result = new notifyMessageReceptionResponse();
        return result;
    }
}
```

How can i change my webservice so i can accept messages with attachments?

Answer (score 0):

these are mime / swa type of attachments. wcf does not support them by default (only mtom is supported) but you can use [this extension](http://wcfswaencoder.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Does It works for receiving mesages to? And by what i saw in The source code it os extremely hard coded

Comment: according the documentation it is supposed to work both ways (I have not tried).

Comment: This is EXTREMELY hard-coded he use the message ID and should not even be considered one extension but a way the guy worked around his own problem and doesn't even work

Comment: sorry, there is nothing built-in in WCF for that so that sample is the best you can start with

Comment: did you ever get any success with this? I also have to be able to access the request's soap attachments inside the service, and not sure if I can use WCF or not

Comment: I have not tried it myself. the project goal is to receive and send attachments and I believe it will work for your use case.